# Proof that $A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if $A \cup B = B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and B be two subsets of the universal set. Give a rigorous proof of the following theorem. $A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if $A \cup B = B$.

I'm not sure how to prove this. I'm not sure how you do a rigorous proof.

Comment: Remember the definition of set and subset.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $A \cup B = \{x \; | \; x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\}$.
Since we know that $B = A \cup B$, then suppose that there is a $x \in A$ such that $x \not \in B$ (meaning $A$ is not a subset of $B$). From the very definition of $\cup$, it follows that $x \in A \cup B = B$, which is a contradiction. Then there is no such $A$ and $A \subseteq B$.

The other verse is obvious.